# Creating 3 floated divs

Tags: html, css

I am designing the footer for my website.
I am trying to get the mailchimp signup form inside the footer div, but failing to do so. The mailchimp just keeps floating out of the footer. Please check the website and help.

**HTML:**

```
 <!--Footer Starts Here-->
<div class="footer">
    <div class="fblikebox">
    <div class="fb-like-box" style="background:#fff;"data-href="http://www.facebook.com/dreamshream" data-colorscheme="light" data-show-faces="true" data-header="true" data-stream="false" data-show-border="true"></div>
    </div>
    <!--Newsletter Signup Form Starts Here-->
    <div id="mc_embed_signup">
    <form action="http://dreamshream.us5.list-manage2.com/subscribe/post?u=f9d3ecf4654824653602ef8c2&amp;id=fcb9497955" method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" target="_blank" novalidate>
        <label for="mce-EMAIL">Subscribe to our mailing list</label>
        <input type="email" value="" name="EMAIL" class="email" id="mce-EMAIL" placeholder="email address" required>
        <div class="clear"><input type="submit" value="Subscribe" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="button"></div>
    </form>
    </div>
    <!--Newsletter Signup Form Ends Here-->
</div>
<!--Footer Ends Here-->
```

**Related CSS:**

```
.footer{background:#313A72;position:relative;width:100%;clear:both;}
#mc_embed_signup{width:33%;float:right;font:14px Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;}
#mc_embed_signup form {text-align:left;}
#mc_embed_signup h2 {font-weight:bold; padding:0; margin:15px 0; font-size:1.4em;}
#mc_embed_signup input {border:1px solid #999; -webkit-appearance:none;}
#mc_embed_signup input[type=checkbox]{-webkit-appearance:checkbox;}
#mc_embed_signup input[type=radio]{-webkit-appearance:radio;}
#mc_embed_signup input:focus {border-color:#333;}
#mc_embed_signup .button {clear:both; background-color: #aaa; border: 0 none; border-radius:4px; color: #FFFFFF; cursor: pointer; display: inline-block; font-size:15px; font-weight: bold; height: 32px; line-height: 32px; margin: 0 5px 10px 0; padding:0; text-align: center; text-decoration: none; vertical-align: top; white-space: nowrap; width: auto;}
#mc_embed_signup .button:hover {background-color:#777;}
#mc_embed_signup .small-meta {font-size: 11px;}
#mc_embed_signup .nowrap {white-space:nowrap;}     
#mc_embed_signup .clear {clear:none; display:inline;}

#mc_embed_signup label {display:block; font-size:16px; padding-bottom:10px; font-weight:bold;}
#mc_embed_signup input.email {display:block; padding:8px 0; margin:0 4% 10px 0; text-indent:5px; width:58%; min-width:130px;}
#mc_embed_signup input.button {display:block; width:35%; margin:0 0 10px 0; min-width:90px;}

#mc_embed_signup div#mce-responses {float:left; top:-1.4em; padding:0em .5em 0em .5em; overflow:hidden; width:90%;margin: 0 5%; clear: both;}
#mc_embed_signup div.response {margin:1em 0; padding:1em .5em .5em 0; font-weight:bold; float:left; top:-1.5em; z-index:1; width:80%;}
#mc_embed_signup #mce-error-response {display:none;}
#mc_embed_signup #mce-success-response {color:#529214; display:none;}
#mc_embed_signup label.error {display:block; float:none; width:auto; margin-left:1.05em; text-align:left; padding:.5em 0;}
.fblikebox{width:33%;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;}
```

Here is the output:
[image]

See how the signup form is out of the div. I would be grateful if anyone can help on this.

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/jGDCh/)

Comment: Floating? How do you really want your mailchimp subscribe form? Can you please provide an image showing how you really want that?

Comment: In the image I just uploaded, the signup form should actually be inside the blue footer

Comment: Thats happen when you have your `#mc_embed_signup` floated to the right. You want put your facebook likebox lined with your subscribe form, am I right? Just add: `float: left` in your `.fblikebox`. Same property for your `#mc_embed_signup`. But now you'll get another issue :P Cause you do not have **height** property in your _footer_. Just let me now how you going with that.

Comment: Basically, I want to make it a 3-column footer. I would be adding some links to the leftmost column, the likebox in the center, and the signup form in the right. Let me know what changes to make.

Comment: Thank you. It worked. Please make this an answer so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is crete a div with class, for example, `footer_col` inside your `#footer` with *CSS* `.footer_col { width: 32%; float: left; }`. For now you're just asking yourself why I defined `width: 32%`, its just because you can define `margin-left: 1%` to spacing your elements.

Repeat your div 3 times and hand out your code inside. 
First *div* maked is for your leftmost column, second the centered and the last, so, the last is the last one.